# Why is pandas read_csv converters performance much slower and non-vectorized?

Tags: python, performance, csv, pandas, dataframe

**Why is it that passing vectorized functions to the `read_csv` `converters` parameter, they get executed on each value individually, instead of on all values at once?** This is much slower (~60x) than manually converting the corresponding columns afterwards.

#### Description

While reading large csv files (several million rows of mixed data), I used the `converters` parameter of pandas' `read_csv` method to conveniently pass functions that convert strings to datetime objects etc.

However, using the converters parameter is very slow in comparison to manually converting the corresponding columns.

#### Example Code

For illustration, let's convert strings to datetime objects using 3 different methods:

1. converters parameter
2. parse_dates/date_parser parameters
3. manually after loading the csv

Note, the conversion from string to datetime is arbitrary here. This could be replaced with other functions (except for not having the specific parse_dates/date_parser parameters).

```
import pandas as pd # 0.19.2 with python 3.5

# create dummy data
rows = 100000
data = {"dates": pd.date_range("2017-02-27 20:44:23", periods=rows, freq="S")}

# save as temporary file for timeit
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("dummy")

# define converters
def convert_datetime(series):
    return pd.to_datetime(series, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Now, lets see the timeit (iPython) comparisons:

```
# METHOD 1
%%timeit
df = pd.read_csv("dummy", converters={"dates": convert_datetime})
# 1 loop, best of 3: 7.76 s per loop

# METHOD 2
%%timeit
df = pd.read_csv("dummy", parse_dates=["dates"], date_parser=convert_datetime)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop   

# METHOD 3
%%timeit
df = pd.read_csv("dummy")
df["dates"] = convert_datetime(df["dates"])
# 10 loops, best of 3: 129 ms per loop
```

#### Result

The converters' version is roughly 60 times slower than the other ones. To understand this a bit better, I wrapped the convert_datetime function into a little decorator class to count the number of calls:

```
class Counter:
   def __init__(self, func):
       self.func = func
       self.count = 0
   
   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.count += 1
       return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@Counter
def convert_datetime(series):
    return pd.to_datetime(series, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

It revealed that using the converters' parameter calls the `convert_datetime` function for every single value whereas the other versions call the converter function only once. This explains the performance deficit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) (*emphasis mine*),

> `converters` : dict, default None
>
> - Dict of functions for converting **values** in certain columns. Keys can either be    integers or column labels

The idea of the `converters` keyword parameter is to provide functions which act upon individual values, not entire columns. This can be seen by redefining the converter function

```
def convert_datetime(val):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(val, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

```
%timeit pd.read_csv("dummy", converters={"dates": convert_datetime})
1 loop, best of 3: 2.81 s per loop
```

And as you can imagine, this amounts to a lot of Python function calls.

---

As for *why* the converters parameter doesn't accept vectorized functions, *my best guess* would be that they offer somewhat less flexibility than the current implementation. With the idea being that you can **parse** necessary columns of dates, etc. which may require some parsing logic with vectorized `parse_dates`, `date_parser` already, and most further column operations could be done post-read with vectorized methods.

In other words, being able to parse elements which *have* to end up in a different type (like datetimes) is convenient to have vectorized methods for in `read_csv`. Beyond that, `converters` is just a convenience parameter which can flexibly act on individual values - as further vectorized methods can just be done post-read anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess there is no real answer to the *why* question but now it is clear under which circumstances it makes sense to employ the `converters`.

Comment: @pansen Yeah, that part of the answer is speculative, but probably just because there are already tools to perform these vectorized computations - `converters` is more of a concession if you absolutely _need_ to convert something else upon reading.